# The type JFreeChartRenderer is deprecated, what method should I use?

Tags: jasper-reports, jfreechart, deprecated

I new with JFreeChart, I tried to used it in jasperreport, I have seen a [question](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/513798/how-insert-jfreechart-object-make-chart) on how to insert a JFreechart object in jasperreport, and one of responses works, but the method used is deprecated:

```
JFreeChartRenderer jrc = new JFreeChartRenderer( SpiderChart.createChart2());
```

what is the new method to use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct substitution of `JFreeChartRender` is the [`DrawChartRendererImpl`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/charts/util/DrawChartRendererImpl.html)

```
new DrawChartRendererImpl(org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart chart, ChartHyperlinkProvider chartHyperlinkProvider);
```

another method is to provide an `java.awt.image.BufferedImage`, that you can retrive from JFreechart

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = chart.createBufferedImage(width, height);
```

Note, however that the normally you included it directly in you jrxml (from IDE you can drag the chart component into the report)

Example of **pie chart** jrxml

```
<pieChart>
    <chart>
        <reportElement x="89" y="100" width="200" height="100" uuid="b96a1b13-4bf0-4983-8168-97b80abdae04"/>
        <chartTitle/>
        <chartSubtitle/>
        <chartLegend/>
    </chart>
    <pieDataset>
        <keyExpression><![CDATA[$F{fieldKey}]]></keyExpression>
        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{fieldValue}]]></valueExpression>
    </pieDataset>
    <piePlot>
        <plot/>
        <itemLabel/>
    </piePlot>
</pieChart>
```

These are the [Standard chart types](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/standard-charts-chart-types) you can use, 
if you are using JasperSoft Studio (and similar in iReport) see [Creating Charts and Datasets with Jaspersoft Studio](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/creating-charts-and-datasets-jaspersoft-studio)

Comment: I do not want to use Jasper chart, I'm using JFreeChart and it's works, but the method used to render charts, is deprecated, and I don't know the new syntax

Comment: @hasanehas also JasperReports use JFreeChart in standard chart types, that is the way to use JFreeChart in jasper reports now.

Comment: The alternative is that you pass it as an for example a BufferedImage in parameters or datasource.

Comment: that it I pass it as an image